# Not matching correct parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to overwrite a subdomain to a set of query parameters.

For example, `sub.domain.com` should direct to `index.php?option=com_pages&layout=swf`, while `sub.domain.com/about` should direct to `index.php?option=com_pages&layout=swf/about`.

I currently have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?option=com_pages&layout=swf/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

It works correctly for `sub.domain.com`, but for `sub.domain.com/about`, I'm directed to `index.php?option=com_pages&layout=swf/index.php` and I'm not sure why.

I've ready a few questions on here, a few tutorials and still can't seem to see what I'm seeing. Any assistance is appreciated.

I'm on Apache 2.2 if that makes a difference.

EDIT: I've taken a look at my server and I'm getting the following for $_SERVER:

```
[REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => option=com_pages&layout=swf/about
[QUERY_STRING] => option=com_pages&layout=swf/index.php&option=com_pages&layout=swf/about
```

I'm not sure why its being concatenated like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the QSA-flag which appends the query string.